# Cleaning Docker containers via Jenkins shell on slave

Tags: shell, jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, containers

We have a scenario where we build a product that uses multiple Docker images and containers.

Our Jenkins environment builds the individual components, packages them in containers, and then (usually) deploys them to test instances. Unfortunately, getting these test instances to be clean has become a problem that I'm having trouble solving.

Slaves are Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus). Docker is the most recent stable version for those builds (1.12.3).

Assume that the Jenkins user is properly sshed into the slave device and has sudo permissions via the sudoers file to run Docker commands. The user is also in the `docker` group. Since we start with a running set of containers created via [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Tools), we stop the containers as a Jenkins shell script starting with:

```
docker-compose stop
```

Then we remove those containers and associated volumes with:

```
docker-compose rm -fv
```

Now it comes time to remove the images because we're going to slap a new set of images down in their place. Here, my code has evolved, but it hasn't worked well.

I currently do the following:

```
dockerimagesoutput="$(sudo docker images -q | sort | uniq)"
if [ ! -z "$dockerimagesoutput" ]; then
    sudo docker rmi "${dockerimagesoutput}"
  fi
```

When this runs on the slave, I wind up with

```
sudo docker images -q
+ sort
+ uniq
+ dockerimagesoutput=01b1b8ea71f4
027c45033c40
0b17fb320c4f
182d60ace820
19a515d76e88
.
.
.
c10984351e73
c2c4b1989875
c95d5afc74e2
ca82cd3aa0d4
d0521df160d4
d99ef18f88fd
e01106d204cb
e0b4f8e0248d
f0a4e63c158c
f14a297b157d
f7dbb67755a8
fe35996d49e9
ff1f30708195
+ [ ! -z 01b1b8ea71f4
027c45033c40
0b17fb320c4f
182d60ace820
19a515d76e88
27f52880c6e2
2af6e3c3e3d7
.
.
.
8d6bfee5cecd
8f244f8ae3db
8f72d2d366e9
9393b391526a
97f2023dcc65
a4d2bb5d4d52
ab4148bd2fb9
aee91e3b71a7
b34b797e9fe6
b4d1c74da310
c10984351e73
c2c4b1989875
c95d5afc74e2
ca82cd3aa0d4
d0521df160d4
d99ef18f88fd
e01106d204cb
e0b4f8e0248d
f0a4e63c158c
f14a297b157d
f7dbb67755a8
fe35996d49e9
ff1f30708195 ]
+ sudo docker rmi 01b1b8ea71f4
027c45033c40
0b17fb320c4f
182d60ace820
19a515d76e88
27f52880c6e2
2af6e3c3e3d7
306ad873c7d8
3258b6beb926
4890da71db50
4aa966f33a88
4f9a28709c33
524ef9a2e9fd
549a9df5d9c4
594ea008ad1c
5ac2e713a1e6
62351a723b50
688715837b4c
.
.
.
9393b391526a
97f2023dcc65
a4d2bb5d4d52
ab4148bd2fb9
aee91e3b71a7
b34b797e9fe6
b4d1c74da310
c10984351e73
c2c4b1989875
c95d5afc74e2
ca82cd3aa0d4
d0521df160d4
d99ef18f88fd
e01106d204cb
e0b4f8e0248d
f0a4e63c158c
f14a297b157d
f7dbb67755a8
fe35996d49e9
ff1f30708195
Error response from daemon: page not found
```

There's no way for me to know which image is causing this page not found error, is there? Or is there a cleaner way to remove all of the images from my slave machine to start fresh?

Comment: you can use `xargs` (bit slower)
`docker ps -qa | xargs docker rmi -f`

Comment: do the containers have the same hash as the images? I've always considered them two separate entities, but maybe I haven't read the docs closely enough.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, they are. So it is `docker images -qa | xargs docker rmi -f` and `docker ps -qa | xargs docker rm -f`

Comment: Please make this an answer so I can accept it. It worked beautifully.

Comment: Posted answer. also added extra reference to docker-gc. Should really take a look at that (for debian-based os)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cleaning up images (please note that this will force clean up everything) you can use

```
docker images -qa | xargs docker rmi -f
```

To clean up containers you can use

```
docker ps -qa | xargs docker rm -f
```

Again this will force clean up all containers, even if they are running. You can use the [--filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#/filtering) parameter to filter the containers, i.e. only exited containers

```
docker ps -qa --filter "status=exited" | xargs docker rm -f
```

There is also a nice package by the guys from spotify, [docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc), which will take care of this for you.

**EDIT**
`docker` now also has the [`system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) command available.

> Remove all unused containers, volumes, networks and images (both dangling and unreferenced).

Comment: thank you for this solution "$(docker ps -aq)" was returning null for me

Answer (score 1):

I have a Jenkins Docker slave machine where I build images and push it to the ECR repository.
[The previous commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832500/cleaning-docker-containers-via-jenkins-shell-on-slave/40909362#40909362) helped me in clean up all images and containers on the slave machine.

1. `docker images -qa | xargs docker rmi -f` (clean images)
2. `docker ps -qa | xargs docker rm -f` (clean containers)

Thanks @Rik.

Answer (score 0):

what about `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` ?
in case of sudo necessity just add it before docker.

Comment: This removes the container but not the image used to create it. Docker-compose pulls in images to build containers. I have killed the containers; this is about the images that are left on the slave machine.